# Cant Fetch Tags From Single Post Page

Tags: php, wordpress

I cant seem to retrieve any Tags from a Single Product Page, Despite the Product having at-least 1 tag

```
            <?php 

                $postid = $post->ID; 
                get_the_tags($postid);

                if ($posttags) {
                  foreach($posttags as $tag) {
                    echo $tag->name . ' '; 
                  }
                }
                if ( has_tag( 'cattle' ) ) : ?>

                     <img src="<?php echo home_url()?>/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/Asset-4.png" alt="img">;
                    
                <?php endif; ?>
```

I tried a Variety of different approaches It just seems asif I cant fetch the array, I wish to just Look to see if it contains specific tag then output a small image for it:

As such:

```
 <?php  

    $post_tags = get_the_tags();
    if ( $post_tags ) {
            echo $post_tags[0]->name; 
    }
                                                    
    switch($post_tags){
          case "cattle":
          echo "<img src='" . home_url() . "/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/Asset-4.png' alt='img'>";
          break;
          case "sheep":
          echo "<img src='" . home_url() . "/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/Asset-3.png' alt='img'>";
          break;
          case "goats":
          echo "<img src='" . home_url() . "/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/Asset-2.png' alt='img'>";
          break;
          case "horse":
          echo "<img src='" . home_url() . "/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/Asset-2.png' alt='img'>";
          break;        
          case "pigs":
          echo "<img src='" . home_url() . "/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/Asset-2.png' alt='img'>";
          break;                    
          case "wildlife":
          echo "<img src='" . home_url() . "/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/Asset-2.png' alt='img'>";
          break;                
          case "poultry":
          echo "<img src='" . home_url() . "/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/Asset-2.png' alt='img'>";
          break;
}


//


if($tags){
$tagNames = array_map(function($tag){return $tag->name;},$tagObjects);
}
?>
```

Page Template:

Single-product.php (Using Woocommerece) & using standard Taxonomy on products nothing unique

Comment: If this is woocommerce, you should get products_tag instead right? - like `$tags = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_id(), 'product_tag' );`

Comment: Im silly you were right btw, I just Noticed I messed up something els as well, But the overall issue was not specifying product tag, I thought Get_Tag(): Would do that for you but it seems not